# Unknown override specifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am working on CPP project with multiple classes and I have stuck for a while. I have Particle class (header file):

```
    #pragma once
    #ifndef PARTICLE_H
    #define PARTICLE_H

    class Particle {
    private:
        vec3 pos; // <- here I get an error
        vec3 dir;
        float speed;
        float size;
        float amb[3];
    public:
        Particle();
        Particle(bool sludge);
        inline void setPosX(float posX);
        inline void setPosY(float posY);
        inline void setPosZ(float posZ);
        inline void setSpeed(float speed);
        inline void setSize(float size);
        void setAmb(float amb0, float amb1, float amb2);
        inline float getPosX();
        inline float getPosY();
        inline float getPosZ();
        inline float getDirX();
        inline float getDirY();
        inline float getDirZ();
        inline float getSpeed();
        inline float getSize();
        void renderParticle();
        void renderSludge();
    };

    #endif
```

and cpp file includes (for simplicity):

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Tools.h"
    #include "Particle.h"
    #include "Player.h"
```

and Tools class, which contains struct vec3:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef TOOLS_H
#define TOOLS_H

void distance(float posX1, float posY1, float posZ1, float radius1, float posX2, float posY2, float posZ2, float radius2);
int fibonacci(int num);
GLuint LoadObj(char * file);
GLuint LoadTexture(char * file, int magFilter, int minFilter);
void drawSphere(float r, int divisions);
void OnRender();
void OnReshape(int, int);
void OnKeyPress(unsigned char, int, int);
void OnKeyDown(unsigned char, int, int);
void OnKeyUp(unsigned char, int, int);
void OnTimer(int);

struct vec3 {
    float x, y, z;
};

struct SFace {
    int v[3];
    int n[3];
    int t[3];
};
#endif
```

I get an: `Error    C3646   'pos': unknown override specifier`, I don't understand why, because `Tools.h` seem to be included only once, and Particle class should know that Tools contains `vec3`. I tried to declare `struct vec3` at the beginning of Particle class and it didn't work.

Comment: how does particle.h know about whats in tools.h?

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11? The `override` keyword is new to C++11 and later (though I don't see it used in the code you provided)

Comment: You are likely including `Particle.h` in a file other than `Particle.cpp`. At that point, `Tools.h` may not be included. Include the headers you need in `Particle.h`. There's nothing wrong with including the header twice, specially since it seems to be guarded by both an `#include` guard and `#pragma once`.

Comment: Using both pragmas and include guards is overkill. Stick to one. Also, make a habit of including everything your header needs right in the header. Get rid of nasty setters and getters. And last, but not the least, where is 'override' coming from?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a conclusive answer from the code snippet provided. Please edit your question to contain a [mcve], assuming that producing the MCVE doesn't make the problem obvious to you and eliminate the need for the question. Include with the MCVE your compiler and version number if you need to proceed with this question. Delete the question or update and self-answer if you don't.

Comment: Do not rely on side-effect includes as you are doing with Tools.h and Particle.h! That way leads to madness! Explicitly `#include <Tools.h>` in Particle.h so that it will always get what it needs and you will save yourself countless wasted hours.

Answer (score 0):

Placing `#include "Tools.h"` inside `stdafx.h` seem to eliminate the problem, although I don't understand why. `Tools.h` was included inside all metioned classes here (`Particle` and `Player`) and despite being included multiple times it should be included only once by using `#ifndef` directive. Despite that fact, it seems to me that compiler couldn't see `Tools.h` inside `Particle` class. Someone could please explain why that happened and why placing header inside `stdafx.h` file solved a problem?

Comment: maybe something in `stdafx.h` included `Particle.h` before it ever reached the `#include "Tools.h"`?